# Как при клике на инпут реализовать добавление элемента в массив?

Tags: javascript, input

Есть список чекбоксов, нужно чтобы при выборе определенного чекбокса в пустой массив добавлялся обьект, этот массив нужно использовать для подсчета суммы, вот код:

```
let addToppingBurger = () => {

  let finalArr = new Array();

  toppingCheesEL.addEventListener('click', function() {
    finalArr.push(toppingCheese);
  });

  toppingSaladEL.addEventListener('click', function() {
    finalArr.push(toppingSalad);
  });

  console.log(finalArr);

  return finalArr;
}

let getPrice = function(finalArr) {
  let priceBurger;
  priceBurger = finalBurger.map((el) => el.price).reduce((sum, el) => sum + el, 0);

  return priceBurger;
};

console.log(getPrice(addToppingBurger()));
```

Вот массив finalArr оказывается пустой, элементы не добавляються, не могу понять почему. подскажите, что делаю не так:((

Comment: вы неверно включили код в вопрос, я подправил, но проверьте, что всё верно. Или исправьте, не трогая первые и последние символы.

Comment: Вы вызываете функцию addToppingBurger, она создаёт новый массив и возвращает его вам. Можно обработчики событий и массив вытащить из тела функции, чтобы они могли работать, заполнять массив и не обнуляться. Но что будет если кто-то нажмёт три раза на один чекбокс и два раза на другой? Я бы просто проверял в конце какие чекбоксы отмечены, и не нужны были бы функции и массивы.